# How can I prove that the following is an abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, binary-operations

Let $(G, *)$ be a groupoid in which the following properties hold:

1) $a * (b * c) = (b * a) * c$ for all $a,b,c \in G$;

2) There exists $u \in G$ such that $u * a = a$;

3) For all $a \in G$ there exists $a'$ such that $a' * a = u$.

I'm more interested in the associative/commutative part of this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please put your question in the body, instead of stating it only in the title.

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: @btcgrl I proved that groupoid satisfies the identity and inverse axioms but I got stuck on associativity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, from (3), we have $a'$ such that $a'*a = u$.
Thus by (1) and (2), we have
$$ a*u = a*(a'*a) = (a'*a)*a = u*a = a. $$
Thus it follows from (1) that
$$ a*b = a*(b*u) = (b*a)*u = b*a.$$
Thus $G$ is commutative.
Then the associative follows immediately.